# Executing new tmux session in shell script with exec "$@"

Tags: bash, shell, sh, tmux

I only have a shell (sh, not bash) login over an SSH connection to a remote device. The script ends with `exec "$@"`, which, as I understand, passes on all parameters as strings. 
Now I want to execute that last command in a new tmux session, so that the program would continue in case of a connection loss. 
This is for a robotics project, therefore I am assuming the connection to be partially interrupted.

How can I wrap this into a command, that will run `exec "$@"` in tmux?

I already tried:
`tmux new "exec \"$@\""`
and
`tmux new -s session send-keys "exec \"$@\""`
as well as both variations with only `"exec $@"`

However, nothing seems to work in [shellchecker](https://www.shellcheck.net/) or my draft `.sh` files. I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: To clarify: This is being used with ROS. `Roslaunch` allows a machine tag to ssh into another machine, where it executes a default script, with the last line being `exec "$@"`, after some variable setups. I want to wrap this last section into tmux, in case of connection dropouts.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
exec tmux new -- "$@"
```

If it doesn't work, you can try something like:

```
exec tmux new -- sleep 10000
```

And try to attach to make sure tmux is being run (for example that the script can find tmux).

`sh -x` may also be useful to see what is actually being run.

Also remember that if tmux is already started the environment inside may not be the same as in the script.

Comment: I created a file called `testtmux.sh` now, with the contents: `#!/usr/bin/env sh` and second line `exec tmux new -- "$@"`. When i run it through the terminal with `sh  -x ./testtmux.sh` it pops me into an empty tmux shell. When I run `sh -x ./testtmux.sh pwd` I receive `[exited]` with `62;c` in my next command line. I am clueless

Comment: `pwd` exits immediately, so the tmux server will also exit. Either try something like `sleep 10000` instead, or do `tmux start \; set -g remain-on-exit on \; new -- "$@"` instead.

Comment: tmux is not yet started on the machine, and it keeps throwing the same error. in terms of ROS-ssh access, I get the error `open terminal failed: not a terminal`, when appending `exec tmux new -- "$@"` to the end of my `env.sh`

Comment: You need to add `-d` to new session if you are starting tmux from somewhere without an external terminal like a script. So `tmux new -d ...`.

Comment: `new -d` will start tmux with the session unattached, if you need it to be attached you can try `ssh -t` or `-tt` to force it to create a pty.

Comment: Okay I tried changing it to `exec tmux new -d "$@"` and it keeps returning with an error. Checking the ROS log, I see that the `socket` library from python throws an Error `connection refused`. Is tmux starting a new child process, with a different URI? That would explain a lot...

Comment: tmux starts a new child process.

Comment: good to know, that explains a lot.  thank you for your help Nicholas, I appreciate it.